# How to search in multiple tables using codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, multiple-tables

So i have a searchbox to search in my factories table. it works like a charm, but i'm still new to codeigniter.

**Do i need to use a select to select more than one table in my database?**

My controller function:

```
    function search()
    {
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/search');
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }

    function searchresults()
    {
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match);
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }
```

My model:

```
function get_search($match)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijven');

    return $query->result();
}
```

**I'm also wondering if you can put your searchfunction from the model into the controller. because then i need to make a new model function for each table.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to join two tables and then apply like

```
$this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
$this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
```

**Search for match in table2 in col1,col2**

```
$this->db->or_like('table2.col1',$match);
$this->db->or_like('table2.col2',$match);
```

**Finally join the table to which you have applied likes above with the table1**

```
$this->db->join('table2','table1.id = table2.id');
$query = $this->db->get('bedrijven');
```

Comment: but it does not quite work. when i apply a join the searchresults are empty

Comment: Then check it in DB...may be there is no records with the combination of match and join

Comment: hm the it's a bit confusing. it only shows records who have an id in my second table and in my first table. so when i have a table record with id 1 then it does not show when it hasn't an id 1 in the second table.

Comment: So......if you want them individually then No way....You need to gothrough individually...

Comment: i have a table tags. here i stored tags for my factories. but how more tags i add how often the factory is shown at the searchresults

Comment: Hey am I rude...?No iam just telling you that's it...Iam not such a guy by the way

Comment: i think i have to ask a new question for that then. because it's stupid that it shows me the records more than once.

Comment: that are the rules. you don't just ask two question in one. if you understand what i mean. i'm not scolding about myself.

Answer (score 0):

The example in the User Guide should explain this:

```
$this->db->select('*'); // <-- There is never any reason to write this line!
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

See the whole thing under [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) page in the User Guide.

Comment: i know how joins work but i did not knew how to implement them with search.